# Source line numbers in perf call graph?

Tags: linux, perf

I'm using `perf record -a --call-graph dwarf -p XXX sleep 1` to record some function calls then `perf report` to view that data, however it would be very helpful if I could also see source line numbers to know exactly where each function call was made. For example:

```
-   4.18%  testbinary  testbinary                [.] malloc 
   - malloc 
      - 99.57% operator new(unsigned long)
         + 7.28% MyFunction()
```

I want to know where exactly in `MyFunction()` are those `new operators` called (without me guessing by looking at the whole function source code)

P.S.: Binary is compiled with `-m64 -O2 -ggdb3`

Comment: How did you compile your code? Lines of source are reported in "annotate" mode, focus on the self time of MyFunction and press "a" in interactive perf report or use `perf annotate` command (with some symbol `-s=MyFunction`).

Comment: @osgx going into annotate mode looks like what I need, however it seems I can only annoatate the topmost function (in this case `malloc`). Even if I go with the cursor on the `MyFunction` (or even deeper), when I annotate it I get the annotation for `malloc` and NOT for the selected function. When I select my function and press the right arrow key, I see the option `Annotate MyFunction()`, but when I click on that option no luck, I get the same annotation, `malloc` one

P.S. Compiling with `-m64 -O2 -ggdb3`

Comment: Shocker, just find the MyFunction as topmost; when it has the "self" events (you can use search with <kbd>/</kbd> button, press <kbd>/</kbd> then enter part of MyFunction name. Press <kbd>/</kbd> and enter to see all functions again). What is your kernel version (perf usually has the same version, and there can be some UI problem with older perf)?

Comment: @osgx that worked, however the result is not really the expected one. Checking the function I am interested in as topmost function will show me usage relative to total function time. What I need is to know where those `new operators` are happening in `MyFunction()`.

If I check the topmost function as you explained, all I get is

`anotherFunction("someString");`
`0.12%  lea    -0xc0(%rbp),%rdx`
`callq  std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char`
(the `new` operator is for the string alloc)

which doesn't help me because that 0.12% is relative to the total execution of MyFunction()

Comment: 0.12% is relative of this instruction to this function time: annotate mode does not have info about child functions (callees). This new can be some temporary std::string allocation to call AnotherFunction (can you add to post assembly fragment and source fragment)?

Comment: That's exactly what it is, temporary string allocations, but the idea was to have a list or something of these locations without manually going through the code and find them by manual search. This was a simple example, but complex code will be much harder to trace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I accidentally found it loosely documented in `perf script`, but it applies to other commands as well: `-F` option accepts `srcline`. So you can do `-F+srcline` to add the line number to existing columns.

Example: `perf report -g fractal -F+period,srcline`

```
Samples: 22K of event 'cycles:u', Event count (approx.): 13031011295
  Children      Self        Period  Source:Line                           Command  Shared Object        Symbol
+   99.98%    38.76%    5051224000  test.cpp:7                            a        a                    [.] fib
+   96.42%     0.00%             0  _start+94372992700461                 a        a                    [.] _start
+   96.42%     0.00%             0  __libc_start_main+140304673091826     a        libc-2.29.so         [.] __libc_start_main
+   96.42%     0.00%             0  test.cpp:13                           a        a                    [.] main
+   21.47%    21.47%    2797741850  test.cpp:8                            a        a                    [.] fib
+   16.69%    16.69%    2174469736  test.cpp:4                            a        a                    [.] fib
+   16.37%    16.36%    2132462705  test.cpp:6                            a        a                    [.] fib
+    6.69%     6.69%     871128215  test.cpp:5                            a        a                    [.] fib
```

Comment: What version is that? `perf version 3.13.11-ckt39` doesn't have an -F option

Comment: @Shocker wow, 3.13 is very old, 5 years is. I'm using `5.0` which is latest stable, but I imagine the option appeared much earlier. **edit**: actually, as of yesterday latest stable is `5.1`, but whatever.

Comment: Max I can check on my current kernel version is 4.x something. While it has the option I still can't see the line numbers, but judging from your example this is the solution. Thank you. Btw, did you use any special compile flags?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I asked on IRC when the option was added, will reply back when I get an answer.

Comment: While searching for it, I stumbled upon [this blog post](https://www.kdab.com/improved-handling-inlined-frames-linux-perf-report/), which describes one more way: `perf report -g srcline`. What it does with regard to the question, is showing source lines when you expand a call chain *(for some reason at top level source lines not shown)*.

Comment: "Btw, did you use any special compile flags": well, I didn't use anything besides the `-g` option, that is. It's no special, you just not gonna have debugging information otherwise, but I thought it may be worth to mention explicitly. I usually use `-g3` as it adds even more stuff, but for line numbers just `-g` is enough.

Comment: Sorry, you were correct the whole time, during these last tests I forgot about the `-g` compile option (I have it on my main app). I see lines too now... btw the exact version I was able to test was `4.4.90`, it was probably added in version 4? Either way

Answer (score 8):

Fragments (full lines) of source code are printed by perf in annotate mode ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-annotate.1.html); relevant part of [The Perf Tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Source_level_analysis_with_perf_annotate)). Use `perf annotate -s=MyFunction` or in `perf report` scroll down to the subtree where your MyFunction is root of tree (line where self time is reported; you can use <kbd>/</kbd> command to search for it) and then select <kbd>a</kbd> button (or <kbd>Enter</kbd> then Annotate "MyFunction").

Source code and its lines should be visible near assembly lines in Annotate mode. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-annotate.1.html

> This command reads the input file and displays an annotated version
>          of the code. If the object file has debug symbols then the source
>          code will be displayed alongside assembly code.
>
> ```
>    -l, --print-line
>        Print matching source lines (may be slow).
>   --source
>       Interleave source code with assembly code. Enabled by default,
>        disable with `--no-source`.
>    -s, --symbol=<symbol>
>        Symbol to annotate.
> ```

Perf report may use srclines in sorting (`--sort=` option) but instructions are unclear. Its man page documents `--source` option too, but apparently it is used only in Annotate some_function mode: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html

> ```
>   --source
>        Interleave source code with assembly code. Enabled by default,
>        disable with --no-source.
> ```